# processing the next event in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, eventqueue

For an application where each request may take a second or two, is it possible to only process a piece of operative code on each iteration of the event loop?
For example:

```
function foo()
{
    ...operative code...
    ...start processing the next event here...
    ...continue with foo() here....
}
```

Would it be something like this?

```
function foo()
{
    ...operative code...
    process.nextTick(function() {
        ...continue with foo() here...
    });
}
```

And if that is the way to do it, does Node automatically start processing whichever event is next in the queue?

Comment: Is your operative code IO based? Usually when I have something that is running for a second or two it's mostly IO time. If this is the case, then node will handle concurrency automatically as it's IO model is non-blocking.

Comment: @tilleryj Assuming it isn't IO based, is there a way to jump to the next event and come back later to continue processing?

Comment: @tilleryj And I realize it would take A LOT of code for a non IO function to take more than a second. But I'm really just trying to get a feel for how the event loop works, and how much control I have over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the time is spent in IO, node's non-blocking model will automatically handle concurrency.

If it's not spent in IO, then you're right in using process.nextTick to defer the execution of your code so that other requests have a change to be handled. Here is a good writeup:

http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick

Comment: Thank you. Also, are all of node's IO calls sequential? Say I have something like, `db.query(query, callback1); db.query(anotherQuery, callback2);`. Will callback1 always be called first?

Comment: No. They will be called in the order in which the queries return.

Comment: But what if both calls involve writing to disk? Maybe something like this would better illustrate my question, `file.write(somethingLong,callback1); file.write(somethingShort,callback2);`. Wouldn't callback1 always get called first in this case?

Comment: Not sure. However the docs for fs.write say you shouldn't call write more than once on the same file without waiting for a callback: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct, you should be dividing the work into smaller blocks of execution and schedule the next block with `process.nextTick`. All the other scheduled events that need to be executed at the next tick will be handled prior to your block of required execution.